# How to write a c++ wrapper for python iterables?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have a C++ function which takes a `vector< pair< pair<string,string>, string > >` which I wish to call from python.

I wrote a wrapper as below:

```
bool create_cache_wrapper(boost::python::tuple tup_)
{
  vector< pair< pair<string,string>, string > > rbv;
  for(int i=0;i<py::len(tup_);++i)
  {
    std::string start,end,bucket;
    bucket = py::extract<std::string>(tup_[i][1]);
    start = py::extract<std::string>(tup_[i][0][0]);
    end = py::extract<std::string>(tup_[i][0][1]);
    rbv.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(start,end),bucket));
  }
  return create_cache(rbv);
}
```

I have registered this function with python as below:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_lib)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("create_cache", create_cache_wrapper);
}
```

This works fine but the issue is, it accepts only a tuple but not a list. How do I write the wrapper such that it works any sequence container in python? Is there a better way to do this without having to write a wrapper? I want the python api to be simple like

```
create_cache( ( (('',''),'b1'), ) )
create_cache( [ (('',''),'b1')  ] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use [boost python iterator wrappers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/v2/stl_iterator.html) to achieve what you described - it works with any type of iterable. I adapted your code below so you have an idea on how to do it yourself:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/stl_iterator.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

bool create_cache_wrapper(object iterable)
{
  stl_input_iterator<object> end;
  for(std_input_iterator<object> i(iterable); i!=end; ++i)
  {
    std::string start,end,bucket;
    bucket = py::extract<std::string>((*i)[1]);
    start = py::extract<std::string>((*i)[0][0]);
    end = py::extract<std::string>((*i)[0][1]);
    rbv.push_back(make_pair(make_pair(start,end),bucket));
  }
  return create_cache(rbv);
}
```

You can go all the way using `stl_input_iterator`, even for the your pairs inside the first iterable.

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished by making the wrapper take an object instead:

```
bool create_cache_wrapper(boost::python::object tup_)
{
    // ...
}
```

`py::len()` and the indexing operators should work on objects, and they should raise a Python error if the type in question does not support `len()` or indexing.  This should allow the caller to provide *any* indexable type, even user-defined ones!

Comment: How do I register this template function with python?

Comment: @balki You would have to register a different function that takes any Python object and calls the appropriate template instantiation for lists and tuples, and raises an error for any other type.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Actually, one need not use templates.  Let me amend my answer.

Comment: Works for list and tuple but not for generators/iterators.
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: Is there a way to loop a python iterable in c++?

Comment: @balki I would assume that if `py::len()` exists that `py::next()` also does.  Perhaps you can try `next()`-based iteration instead, which does not require knowing a length up-front.

Comment: Nope `py::next()` does not exist

Comment: You may need to use the C API instead.  See [Iterator Protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/iter.html).  (You can use `tup_.ptr()` to get the `PyObject *` for the passed object.)

Comment: Using `py::stl_input_iterator<py::object> itr(tup_), itr_end;` worked